# iOS - CoreImage - Add an effect to partial of image

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-graphics, avfoundation, core-image

I just have a look on CoreImage framework on iOS 5, found that it's easy to add an effect to whole image.
I wonder if possible to add an effect on special part of image (a rectangle). for example add gray scale effect on partial of image/

I look forward to your help.

Thanks,
Huy

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: I dont think they are the same. this question is about CoreImage framework

Answer (score 5):

Watch session 510 from the WWDC 2012 videos. They present a technique how to apply a mask to a `CIImage`. You need to learn how to chain the filters together. In particular take a look at:

- `CICrop`, `CILinearGradient`, `CIRadialGradient` (could be used to create the mask)
- `CISourceOverCompositing` (put mask images together)
- `CIBlendWithMask` (create final image)

[image: Example: Pixelate faces]

The filters are documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to copy the CIImage (so you now have two), crop the copied CIImage to the rect you want to effect, perform the effect on that cropped version, then use an overlay effect to create a new CIImage based on the two older CIImages.

It seems like a lot of effort, but when you understand all of this is being set up as a bunch of GPU shaders it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score -3):

```
     typedef enum {
   ALPHA = 0,
   BLUE = 1,
   GREEN = 2,
  RED = 3
```

} PIXELS;

```
- (UIImage *)convertToGrayscale:(UIImage *) originalImage inRect: (CGRect) rect{
       CGSize size = [originalImage size];
   int width = size.width;
  int height = size.height;

// the pixels will be painted to this array
uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

// clear the pixels so any transparency is preserved
memset(pixels, 0, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

// create a context with RGBA pixels
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, 
                                             kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

// paint the bitmap to our context which will fill in the pixels array
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [originalImage CGImage]);

for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        uint8_t *rgbaPixel = (uint8_t *) &pixels[y * width + x];

        if(x > rect.origin.x && y > rect.origin.y && x < rect.origin.x + rect.size.width && y < rect.origin.y + rect.size.height) {

            // convert to grayscale using recommended method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale

            uint32_t gray = 0.3 * rgbaPixel[RED] + 0.59 * rgbaPixel[GREEN] + 0.11 * rgbaPixel[BLUE];

            // set the pixels to gray in your rect

            rgbaPixel[RED] = gray;
            rgbaPixel[GREEN] = gray;
            rgbaPixel[BLUE] = gray;
          }
    }
}

// create a new CGImageRef from our context with the modified pixels
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

// we're done with the context, color space, and pixels
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
free(pixels);

// make a new UIImage to return
UIImage *resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];

// we're done with image now too
CGImageRelease(image);

return resultUIImage;
```

}

You can test it in a UIImageView:

```
  imageview.image = [self convertToGrayscale:imageview.image inRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
```

Comment: This does not answer the question how to apply a filter to part of the image. The code does not use CoreImage (GPU image processing) but does image processing on the CPU!