# How to apply filters/color on selected image area in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, core-graphics

I have an image of a my face and I just want to apply some filter or color on lips/eyes etc. I have detected the areas but my issue is how to add color there so that is looks natural and mix with existing image.

Please see the image below to have better idea what I need. See color applied on lips which is pretty much natural,

[image]

Comment: This questions already discussed many times. You can use CoreImage, GPUFilter, CoreGraphics... Please use search before...

Comment: Are you asking *how* to apply a filter to a specific area, or *what* filters/techniques you should apply?

Comment: Anna, I am trying to change color or add some filter to pixels of UIImage. I have added filters over simple image using some rects but that does not look natural and I need the filter to look natural blend with original image at some specific area of image.

Comment: @MobileDeveloperiOSAndroid have you get solution of this problem?I am facing same issue. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use Following code to set any color to given filtered area. For Demo, I have used here rectangle to be get painted, you can use any other bounded area to fill up. Here i have used Yellow color to fill up, you can change that color too.

```
UIImage *image=...;//Add Code for getting Main Image
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:imageRect];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,0.0,0.5);//set RGBA for color to fill in given area
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);//set RGBA for Border color to add in given area
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(5,5,10,10);//Here, Use the area to be coloured, rightnow i have used Rectangle
CGContextFillRect(context,rect);
CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, rect, 3);//Set Border Width in 3rd argument
CGContextSaveGState(context);

UIImage *newimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(newimage) writeToFile:FileName] atomically:YES];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I have tried this, close to what I need but not perfect one. Have a look at picture that I have posted in my question to have better idea.

Comment: Here You have to create Bezier path for that bounded region, and replace rectangle with that... that's it

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to do this,one of them can be as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064156/997043)

The other approach can be u can create a UIView of the size same as size of your identified area,with whatever color you want and add that view as a subview on the face .

Comment: that will only add layer over the original image that will not look natural, I have tried this also. I need some method to change color of pixels inside uiimage based on some location or frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the image and then apply a CoreImage filter to adjust the colors inside of a masked area that you've defined.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322027/ios-coreimage-add-an-effect-to-partial-of-image) outlines how to do this. Making it look natural more applies to just learning how to create filters that do what you want to the images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some drawing customisation for particular image view. Here is some SO Q/A.

[how to change the color of an individual pixel in uiimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152894/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-individual-pixel-in-uiimage)

[iPhone : How to change color of particular pixel of a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462129/iphone-how-to-change-color-of-particular-pixel-of-a-uiimage)